# Fetching data (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, fetch

i got a js request to my postgresql database, i'm trying to make a registration.
I tried to send react state before that, but now i just filled it up with constant values.

It send an empty body. `Body: null`. `GET` request works, the problem happens only when i use `POST` request

```
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/user", {
   method: "POST",
   mode: 'no-cors',
   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
   body: JSON.stringify({
     "username": "lpkopjp",
      "email": "mimiomo@mail.ru",
      "password": "12345678",
      "repeat_password": "12345678"
   })
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD: the problem was solved, i've installed cors package and added `app.use(cors());` into my backend code (node.js). also you have to delete `no cors mode`